# Blocks as Fields in Content Type

Tags: blocks

I really like the ability to edit a block in Drupal on whatever page it's on--without having to drill down through menus.  However, a block doesn't seem to be a valid field for a content type.  If something is promoted to the front page, I can edit the item in a similar fashion to a block.

A work-around is to create a page, and put the block on the page.  However this creates additional maintenance.  For instance if the page is deleted, someone has to remember to delete the block too.

Is there any way of creating a field type which would be a block?  Or even better, is there any way in which a text field can be edited on the fly if it's not on the home page?

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The [display suite](http://drupal.org/project/ds) module has a "region to block" in its extras. This lets you put any of the fields displayed into its own block which can then be put where you want but I believe that editing will still take you to the full node edit page anyway.

For editing on the fly you should look into the [jeditable](http://drupal.org/project/jeditable) module and/or [editablefields](http://drupal.org/project/editablefields) module.